# Is everything a list in scheme?

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, chicken-scheme

Along with the book "Simply Scheme" (Second Edition) i'm watching the "Computer Science 61A - Lectures" on youtube. On the lectures , the tutor uses Stk interpreter, but i'm using chicken scheme interpreter.

In the first lecture he uses the "first" procedure which if it's called like :

```
(first 'hello)
```

it returns "h".

On the book of "Simply Scheme" it has an example of how first can be implemented:

```
(define (first sent)
  (car sent))
```

Which to my testing and understanding works if sent is a list .
I'm trying to understand if it's proper to say that "everything is a list" in scheme.
To be more specific where's the list in *'hello* and if there is one, why it doesn't work in first procedure as it's written in the book?

Also if every implementation is written with "everything is a list" in mind why the same code **does not** work in all scheme implementations?

Comment: The short answer is "No, not everything in Scheme is a list." While lists predominate, there are other structures available.

Comment: Simply Scheme is not following standard Scheme. In particular the function `first` has been redefined in Simply Scheme to work on symbols. See the package by @dyoo http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/dyoo/simply-scheme.plt/2/2/planet-docs/manual/index.html if you want to use Simply Scheme in DrRacket.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is a common misconception because lists are so pervasive in Scheme programming (and often functional programming in general). Most Scheme implementations come with many data types like strings, symbols, vectors, maps/tables, records, sets, bytevectors, and so on.

This code snippet `(first 'hello)` is unlikely to work in most Schemes because it is not valid according to the standard. The expression `'hello` denotes a *symbol*, which is an opaque value that can't be deconstructed as a list (the main thing you do with symbols is compare them with `eq?`). This is probably a quirk of Stk that is unfortunately taught by your book.

See [*The Scheme Programming Language*](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/) for a more canonical description of the language. If you just want to learn programming, I recommend [*HtDP*](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/).

Answer (score 3):

Not *everything* is a list in Scheme. I'm a bit surprised that the example you're showing actually *works*, in other Scheme interpreters it will fail, as `first` is usually an alias for `car`, and `car` is defined only for [**`cons` pairs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons). For example, in Racket:

```
(first 'hello)
> first: expected argument of type <non-empty list>; given 'hello

(car 'hello)
> car: expects argument of type <pair>; given 'hello
```

Scheme's basic data structure is the cons pair, with it it's possible to build arbitrarily linked data structures - in particular, singly-linked lists. There are other data structures supported, like vectors and hash tables. And of course there are primitive types - booleans, symbols, numbers, strings, chars, etc. So it's erroneous to state that *"everything is a list"* in Scheme.

Comment: The lecturer was probably using Clojure ;p

Comment: Simply Scheme: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-toc2.html  It provides re-definitions for *first*, *rest*, etc that work on symbols, numbers, and lists.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to Simply Scheme: the functions *first* and *rest* are not the standard ones from  the Scheme standard, nor ones that come built-into DrRacket.  The Simple Scheme API is designed as part of the Simply Scheme curriculum to make it easy to work uniformly on a variety of data.  We can't make too many assumptions on how the underlying, low-level implementation works from just the experience of using the Simply Scheme teaching language!  There's a runtime cost involved with making things that simple: it does not come for free.