# Selectors in Scheme R6RS

Tags: scheme, r6rs

I'm reading a old book

> Simply Scheme: Introducing Computer Science

you can find it [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch5/words.html#ft2) .

In the fifth section it introduces the "selectors", operators like the following:

```
(first 'abcd) ;-> A
(butfirst 'abcd) ;-> BCD
```

and so on..

Does it exist something similar in R6RS? (since this operators are not defined).

Comment: You will need to port the Simply Scheme preamble which is not compatible with R6RS. I am not even sure it is possible as it uses 'funny' constructs.

Comment: This question was asked before on SO. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593429/is-everything-a-list-in-scheme). If you want to learn standard Scheme, Simply Scheme is probably not the best book to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, this will probably be quite difficult.

Another aspect is that Simply Scheme sees symbols as 'strings'.

With that info you could write the following:

```
(define (first s)
  (string->symbol (string (car (string->list (symbol->string s))))))

(define (butfirst s)
  (string->symbol (apply string (cdr (string->list (symbol->string s))))))
```

Also note that symbols are case-sensitive in R6RS, so the result will be the same case case passed to the procedure.